# Minting with Wagmi

Tags: mint, wagmi

I am using Wagmi hooks in my dapp. Also, I have utilized RainbowKit for wallet connection. Now, I am trying to use Wagmi to execute the mint function of my smart contract. As shown, it takes three arguments.

```
function mint(uint256 _amount, string memory _uri, bytes memory _data) public onlyOwner {}
```

I am aware that to get proper results from  issuing transactions by Wagmi, we need to populate these hooks in order, **usePrepareContractWrtie()**, **useContractWrite()**, and **useWaitForTransaction()**

Now, let's see what my question is. In my **usePrepareContractWrite()**, I am passing some fixed parameters to the mint function to practice how this approach works. For instance,  `[100,"",[]]`  ( according to my contract's mint function ). It works great for me.

However, I am facing an error whenever I try to use my form inputs ( dynamic params ), which are stored in the useState() hook in my component. In other words, I can only mint tokens based on fixed conditions and can not yet mint NFTs according to my inputs.

```
const { config } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    address: f_nftaddress,
    abi: F_NFT.abi,
    functionName: 'mint',
    args: [ 200, "", []],
})
```

My form input states:

```
const [ formInput, updateFormInput ] = useState({ quantity: "", name: "", description: "" });
const [ tokenUrl, setTokenUrl ] = useState(null);
```

In `usePrepareContractWrite()`, In `args: [ 200, "", []]`, I need `formInput.quantitiy` to be used instead of `200`, and `tokenUrl` instead of `""`.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To use the form input values in the usePrepareContractWrite() hook, you can destructure the values from the formInput state and pass them as arguments in the args property. For example:

```js
const { quantity, name, description } = formInput;
const { config } = usePrepareContractWrite({
  address: f_nftaddress,
  abi: F_NFT.abi,
  functionName: "mint",
  args: [quantity, tokenUrl, [name, description]],
});
```

This will use the quantity and tokenUrl values from the formInput state and the tokenUrl state in the args property of the usePrepareContractWrite() hook.

Comment: Can we replace the "config" ( destruction result ) with some arbitrary strings like "Sina"?

Comment: You can by renaming it like so: `const { config: sina } = usePrepareContractWrite...`